# Suggestion for Screeps: Option to put the Console/Script-Editor to the left

Tags: screeps

This is a suggestion to improve the screeps experience for laptop users (or people with a "small" screen at about 17''). :)

It would be nice to have the option, to put the console to the left part of the screen. When I am using my laptop, the view of the room is pretty small when writing code in the console at the same time.

If the console is displayed at the left hand part of the screen a user would have the full height of the browser and approximately 1/3rd of the width of the browser to write code. The remaining screen (as most of the screens today have 16:9 aspect ratio) would be enough to display the room plus the sidebar to the right.

Could that be a feature for a future version?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making a feature suggestion for an application. This should be directed toward an official support channel for the application, not posted here.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't found an official support channel for this game. When there is one, I'm glad to move this feature request in the correct place. Maybe you know about one?

Comment: go to http://www.screeps.com, scroll to the bottom and click "Contact Us." Or tweet at them. Or go to their Facebook page. But you have very nearly **zero** chance of anyone who can actually respond to this suggestion in an official capacity on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've managed to change the css with Chrome DevTools to get this result:
http://postimg.org/image/f5pzqxall/full/. The game was working, but it's just a temporary hack untill the devs decide to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alroc mentioned

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making a
>   feature suggestion for an application. This should be directed toward
>   an official support channel for the application, not posted here.

Perhaps you can try posting it in the repo over at [Screeps github Issues](https://github.com/screeps/script-samples/issues/4)